# Remove first-child padding when div has second child using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two anchor  tags within a single div. I want to apply the padding style only if the div has one anchor tag. For example the set 2, shouldn't show padding

```css
.email a {
  padding-top:10px;
  display: block;
} // for set 1

//I need to remove padding for a tag when div having two a tag like set 2
```

```html
    Set 1:
    <div class="email">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
    Set 2:
    <div class="email">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) selector:

```css
.email a {
  display: block;
}

.email a:only-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
Set 1:
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
Set 2:
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using css's `:only-child` selector can accomplish this! For example,

```
.email a:only-child{
  padding-top:10px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.email a {
  padding-top:10px;
  display: block;
} 

.email:not(:first-child) a{
  padding-top: 0;
}
//I need to remove padding for a tag when div having two a tag like set 2
```

```html
Set 1:
    <div class="email">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
    Set 2:
    <div class="email">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.email > a:not(:only-child):first-child { padding-top:0px}
```

Obviously, you can adjust the CSS there to adjust your original style for the .email a class

You can see a working Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/37js9wae/3/

```css
.email a {
  padding-top:30px;
  display: block;
}

.email > a:not(:only-child):first-child { padding-top:0px}
```

```html
Set 1:
    <div class="email">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
Set 2:
    <div class="email">
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
      <a href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works in Chrome. Not sure about ALL other browsers. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I misread, I thought you wrote you wanted to remove a style to the first element IF it wasn't the only child.  Still a good snippet though. ;)